# Improve result of classification problem on highly imbalanced dataset

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I am running LinearSVC model using sklearn for my classification problem on imbalanced dataset and get the result as belows:

```
confusion matrix:
[[43677 28222]
 [ 5309  9575]]

classification report:
   precision    recall  f1-score   support

   class 0:       0.72      0.69      0.71    133958
   class 1:       0.70      0.73      0.72    133958

   micro avg       0.71      0.71      0.71    267916
   macro avg       0.71      0.71      0.71    267916
weighted avg       0.71      0.71      0.71    267916

               precision    recall  f1-score   support

class 0:       0.89      0.61      0.72     71899
class 1:       0.25      0.64      0.36     14884

    micro avg       0.61      0.61      0.61     86783
    macro avg       0.57      0.63      0.54     86783
 weighted avg       0.78      0.61      0.66     86783
```

Look at the result, do you have any suggestion for me to improve it? (I am using oversampling method to balance training dataset)

What I am concerned is to filter out all instances in class 1 from the data, should I just look at precision/recall of class 1 or should I use any other metrics to evaluate how good my model is?

Comment: `class_weight` from https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html with and without oversampling should be one of the first things to try.

Answer (score 0):

oversampling won't help all the time (i.e. it just duplicates samples to balance the data).
try different approaches, for example 'Synthetic Minority Over-sampling Technique'.
For more details refer the following, [SMOTE](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html)